# Magento 2 Admin Menu Fatal Error-session time out

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, session

magento 2 admin grid session time out after getting error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Menu.php:233 Stack trace: #0 D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1035): Magento\Backend\Block\Menu->getCacheKeyInfo() #1 D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1093): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getCacheKey() #2 D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() #3 D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() #4 D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('menu') #5 D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('menu') #6 D in D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Menu.php on line 233

Comment: have u installed any extension earlier ?

Comment: Nope , i have not installed any extension

Comment: @Rutvee Sojitra have you found any issue ? what's the fix? I am having this issue too

Answer (score 0):

It seems your custom module admin controller does not extend from backend controller... so you need to change and extend from \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action to \Magento\Backend\App\Action